# How to test in app billing while I have an 'Unpublished production track' on google play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Currently I am trying to add In-App-Billing to my android App.

My Android app at some point was released to the play store but we have decided to unpublished it because it has a lot of missing features.

So, now I am trying adding in app billing to my app.

But i am running into an issue: when I try to make the actual purchase, it errors with message "the item you requested is not available for purchase".

- Yes, i have tested with dummy productId (android.test.purchased), and they are working as expected.
- Yes, I have uploaded a release apk to the beta test.
- Yes, the products are all activated.
- Yes, locally i am testing with the same release apk (therefore same version code, and version string)
- Yes, I have waited for a DAY now.

What am I missing here? Is the only way to "publish" my production track, and download beta test from google play to test it?

Answer (score 1):

Your APK has to be the same as the one from Google Play. You say

"Yes, locally i am testing with the same release apk (therefore same version code, and version string)". But is it the same signature? If you are enrolled in Google Play signing, then the version you have locally may be different from the one from Google Play as it is signed with a different key.

Comment: Well. I was testing with the APK that I uploaded to google play beta test. They should be identical.